# How do I get this bone to stop flying across the screen?

Tags: animation, armature

I have this model that has a bone (bn_l_weapon) that controls a weapon, which is loaded in as a separate mesh.  In Noesis, the bone behaves normally:

[image]

In that image, the bone in question is marked in blue, and it's doing what it's supposed to do, situating the weapon in the center of the tank.  When I import the figure into Blender, this happens:

[image]

That's the same bone, but it's flown far off to the side, and I don't know what logic is making Blender do this.  I've tried two different FBX importers and changed every setting I could think of, and this always happens.  How can I get Blender to behave correctly in this situation?

UPDATE: This happens around frame 125 of the animation.

Here's my FBX file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file_premium/wjxbrw6i3glsa30/Drillhorn_problem.zip/file

Comment: the object you share is a robot, is it the same as the one you show? And I can't see any bone that is far away,how does it happen?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this happens around frame 125 of the animation.

Comment: there are some location+rotation+scale keyframes for the bone called bn_l_weapon, not sure why it happened but if it's not surpposed to happen you could remove them from the Dope Sheet?